# Propagate context through parser and action body in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I have distributed tracing information that is carried with requests between services in HTTP headers (specifically for opentracing).

I would like to be able to this information available everywhere, so I can include the trace-id in logs, propagate to downstream requests, etc.

So, I want to parse the headers to create a `Span` before the request is handled, make the span available to the handling code, then do some cleanup after the request has been handled.

### things I've tried:

At first it seemed like a Filter would be the right approach, but there are a few problems with this:

1. Setting thread local storage while calling the next action doesn't help very much, because usually most of the work is done during or after the Accumulator it returns. At which point the thread local storage has been reset.
2. as far as I can tell, there isn't any way to wrap the `Accumulator` so that the accumulation steps are wrapped in a context with a thread local set. The best I've been able to do is to use `Accumulator.source` for the acumulator I return, and then use run the nested actions accumulator with the source from that and a custom materializer that wraps all the methods to set the thread locals. But this still doesn't work, I think because the materializer is dispatching to other thread. I have configured the default dispatcher for akka to keep track of these thread locals, but the materializer seems to be bypassing it in this case.
3. There isn't a way to attach arbitrary data to a RequestHeader, tags only work for strings. And even if there was, I would have to change all of my controllers to read them.

So I've pretty much given up on Filters. My next attempt was to create a custom ActionBuilder to wrap Actions to attach a Span to each request, and run the Action in with thread-locals set. This sort of works, for the body of the actions. However, I'm creating the Span later now, after the body ahs been parsed, and the BodyParser still doesn't have access to it. It's also rather inconvenient, since I now have to change all my controllers to use this to create Actions instead of the `Action` object (and there are a lot of them).

Is there some way to propagate data out of band (meaning, not part of the Body Content itself) from the body parser or earlier to the body of the Action. Or to send data from a Filter to the code executed by an Accumulator?